# Need to place const data at specific location, but the region is in the middle of text section

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I need to put 2KB of const data at an exact location (internal flash) in final binary. This location is currently inside the text section of the memory.

[image]

The only logical way i can think of is to split my code such that i reserve the needed region inside MEMORY {..} definition and explicitly provide new section name for rest of the code.

Is there a much elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a custom embedded target platform you should probably create a custom linker-script for that target. And such a custom script could of course places initialized constant data anywhere it pleases, both in the output file and with different addresses to be used when "loading" the file (to run or to program to flash).

Comment: Yeah.. your linker is your friend, (or, at least, not an implacable enemy, despite any conclusions you may draw from reading the fine manual and struggling with the script:).

Comment: I understand it should be a custom solution, would like to understand what are the different possibilities. The one i am thinking about is to place the text section before the 2KB const data to be explicitly placed there. Then put the 2KB const data, later all the remaining text section follows it .. definitely the new code added.